How to improve testing method B, if Bland-Altman analysis show a near-perfect correlation between the difference and the mean between method A and B?
I have two sets of measurements (two different methods), A and B.
Correlation between the measurements is only modest.

Therefore, I wondered whether there is some inherent bias in (one or both) of the measurement procedures.
Drawing a Bland-Altman plot, I was surprised to get a very significant correlation (see Figure).

This correlation seems to mean that the methods are not measuring the same phenomenon.

Is this right?
Can this information be used to improve one of the methods (i.e. the cheap method)? A log-transform comes to mind ...
Is there indeed some more "information" hidden in this correlation between the difference and the mean?


Please add axis labels to the plot. And I suspect this plot shows only part of the data. One hint is the title "1. controls" which suggests there is at least one more subset of measurements. Also, the figure doesn't seem to align with the statement "the correlation between the measurements were only modest".

As indicated, the plotted is the Bland-Altman plot: this is difference vs. mean of A and B. The "modest correlation" is refering to the actual data, i.e. A vs. B

See also Bland-Altman (Tukey Mean-Difference) plot for differing scales.

Thanks to Jonathan Bartlett from LSHTM:
The problem was very basic and obvious. I was comparing two methods with vastly different variances, as nicely explained here.
In brief, the correlation between difference and mean could be the consequence of two different phenomena:

measurement bias, i.e. the results are dependent on the magnitude of the measurement,
non-equal error variance.


This is interesting & thank you for adding the scatterplot of A and B as well (though it's hard to imagine they are measuring the same phenomenon). Can you expand the answer with a summary of the argument, so that your answer can stand on its own?
